# Java character option pane

Tags: java, joptionpane

I'm doing a basic calculator, I got confuse how to make this do a do while loop for it to execute again. Any suggestions? I'm just starting to learn Java so I'm a beginner. I only have trouble at the "Do you want to try again" Part. Is there a character parse like `Integer.parseInt` for character data types? or string data type? Thank you

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Calc2 op = new Calc2();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    char ans = 0;
    do {
        String c = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Calculator\n" + "1.Addition\n" + "2.Subtraction\n" + "3.Multiplication\n" + "4.Division\n");
        int n1 = Integer.parseInt(c);

        switch (n1) {
            case 1:
                op.add();
                break;
            case 2:
                op.diff();
                break;
            case 3:
                op.prod();
                break;
            case 4:
                op.quo();
                break;
            default:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Input", "Calculator", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

                break;
        }

        String s1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Try again? [Y/N]");
        int a = Integer.parseInt(s1);

    } while (ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to parse a character and should remove:

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(s1);
```

and change the following line:

```
} while (ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y');
```

to:

```
} while (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Try again? [Y/N]").equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
```

and remove the unnecessary lines:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
char ans = 0;
```